# Enforce Multiple Relationships Between Two Tables In Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, relational-database

I want to create (and enforce) multiple "one-to-many" relationships between the primary key of one table to attributes of another.

Hopefully this example will explain better.  I have a table for a character in a game.  The character can hold one item in each hand.:

```
Table: GamePlayer
gamePlayerID    Number  PK
name            Text    Unique
classID         Number  FK->PlayerClass.classID
leftHandItem    Number  FK->Items.itemID
rightHandItem   Number  FK->Items.itemID
```

How do I implement the `leftHandItem -> Items.itemID` and `rightHandItem -> Items.itemID` with enforcing referential integrity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Relationships window, add the Items table twice. The second occurence will automatically get an alias. Use the 2 occurences like if they were 2 distinct tables to create relationships.